# How to create a function that creates a function to constantly return an object's key

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a function that creates a function to constantly return an object's key, but I am unsure of how to write it.

for example, I can do the below:

```
var parent = {data: 123}
var child = {}

child.data = function() {
    return parent.data
}

child.data() // 123
parent = {data: 456}
child.data() // 456
```

This works fine, but I want to create a function that creates the data function, something like:

```
var parent = {data: 123}
var child = {}
create_data_function(parent, child, "data")

child.data() // 123
parent = {data: 456}
child.data() // 456
```

The below would not work, since the "from" variable is reassigned

```
function create_data_function(from, to, key) {
    to[key] = function() {
        return from[key]
    }
}
```

Is creating the create_data_function possible?
I am unsure what to search for to find the solution for this.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder.  The code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ye7onjyu/

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, thank you for trying it out, I should have created a jsfiddle, sorry about that.

Comment: I realised the original example has a typo, what I wanted to do was parent = {data: 456} instead of parent.data = 456, I've forked your fiddle for this case now https://jsfiddle.net/hf664p15/

Comment: @sheeldotme thanks for the jsfiddle

Comment: I've given another try to this, by having an additional context parameter (I think the context parameter is needed for this?): https://jsfiddle.net/5476yx91/, it isn't working on the jsfiddle though

Comment: @T.J.Crowder have edited, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's refer to the initial object that `parent` points to as Object 1, and the new object you assign to `parent` as Object 2.

The value in your `parent` variable is an object reference, initially a reference to Object 1. When you do:

```
 create_data_function(parent, child, "data");
```

the *value* of `parent` is read and passed into `create_data_function`. That value is a reference to Object 1. Nothing, at all, related to the `parent` *variable* is passed into `create_data_function`. The function it creates closes over the `from` argument from the `create_data_function` call that created it, which will always contain a reference to Object 1.

To create a function that does what you describe, the function has to have access to the `parent` variable itself. JavaScript doesn't have any form of pass-by-reference (which lets you pass a reference to a variable into a function), so we have to find another way to give `create_data_function` access to the `parent` variable.

The simplest way is to ensure that `create_data_function` *closes over* `parent`, by defining it in a scope that has access to `parent`, like this:

```js
var parent = {data: 123};
var child = {};
create_data_function(child, "data");
//                   ^---- Note we aren't passing in `parent`

console.log(child.data()); // 123
parent = {data: 456};
console.log(child.data()); // 456

function create_data_function(to, key) {
// Note no `from` ------------^
    to[key] = function() {
        return parent[key];
//             ^^^^^^------ instead we use `parent` directly
    };
};
```

That's possible because `create_data_function` is created in a place where you could use the `parent` variable directly.

But what it if weren't? We'd solve it by passing an *accessor function* into `create_data_function`, like this:

```js
// Note that because `parent` is a local within `test`,
// and `create_data_function` isn't, `create_data_function`
// doesn't have direct access to `parent` (it doesn't *close over*
// `parent`).
function test() {
  var parent = {data: 123};
  var child = {};
  create_data_function(function() {   // So we give it a function to call
    return parent;                    // to get `parent`'s current value
  }, child, "data");

  console.log(child.data()); // 123
  parent = {data: 456};
  console.log(child.data()); // 456
}

function create_data_function(fromAccessor, to, key) {
// Accept the accessor -------^
    to[key] = function() {
        return fromAccessor()[key];
// Call it ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    };
};

test();
```

That's a bit less clunky with ES2015 syntax, because of the new arrow functions:

```js
// THIS EXAMPLE REQUIRES ES2015 SUPPORT IN YOUR BROWSER

function test() {
  var parent = {data: 123};
  var child = {};
  create_data_function(() => parent, child, "data");
  // The accessor func ^^^^^^^^^^^^

  console.log(child.data()); // 123
  parent = {data: 456};
  console.log(child.data()); // 456
}

function create_data_function(fromAccessor, to, key) {
    to[key] = function() {
        return fromAccessor()[key];
    };
};

test();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes a bit clunky with javascript, but seems there is no way around that, a good idea to wrap the variable in a function

Comment: just curious, what do you think of passing in a context parameter like in https://jsfiddle.net/L7stc9rd/? It is modifying the original function parameters in the question of course, but aside from that it would work fine I think? Although it runs into issues on jsfiddle

Comment: @John: That only works if `parent` is a property of an object. It will be if `var parent` is at global scope, but normally you want to avoid globals, so... (Your fiddle isn't working because of jsFiddle's surprising default of wrapping your code in `window.onload = function() { /*...your code here...*/};`, so your `var parent` isn't at global scope.)